# Can tilde symbol expanded to a whole word

Tags: symbols, math-operators, tilde

I am new to using the tilde symbol in latex using the `\tilde`. It appears above one letter only. It seems to be this can be overlooked. Can I expand it somehow to be clearer? can the symbol be expanded to the whole word?

Comment: The package `yhmath` provides `\widetilde`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible way is to use `\widetilde` from `yhmath`, but it's a math mode command only, meaning that long words will look ugly unless using `\text` again.

In the very end, it does not look really nice for a word that has more than three or four letters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}


$\widetilde{\text{alongword}}$
\end{document}
```